# Rails: Obscuring certain fields when using content tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `content_tags` to view some db queries, however, in the embedded HTML, I see some critical user information like your email address connected to your User column is visible. 
E.g. `:&quot;xx.yy@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;`

How do I obscure some fields? Should I sort of be doing a loop in the controller, and getting rid of sensitive fields such as that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating custom scopes in my model:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :users_database_listing, -> { select(:field_name1, :field_name2...)}
  scope :another_scope_for_users, -> { select(:names, :age, :agen) }
end
```

in controller, you can call them normal as you do with methods:

```
record = Record.users_database_listing
```

this will run query like this:

```
SELECT field_name1, field_name2 from records
```

what's great is that you can chain multiple scopes together.  for more details see the following documenation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope